# jQuery Masonry with Wordpress not displaying right

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I've set up Masonry to work with a Custom Post Type on a site I'm trying to build, but I have a problem with the way Masonry's displaying my posts. Instead of always having the same margins and flowing beautifully on the page, the posts stack in three (with exception of a few) and then skip huge amounts of the page before stacking in yet another three.

Here's an [example of what's going wrong](http://bildr.no/view/1419185).

My head:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#kampanjer-container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.kampanjepin',
            columnWidth: 226,
            singleMode: true });
    });</script>
```

Here's the page template loop:

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
            <div id="kampanjer-container">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'kampanje',
                        'posts_per_page' => '15',
                    );
                    $kampanje = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if( $kampanje->have_posts() ) { while( $kampanje->have_posts() ) {
                            $kampanje->the_post(); ?>
                            <article class="kampanjepin">
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
                                    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                                    <div class='kampanje-content'>
                                        <?php the_content() ?>
                                    </div>
                            </article><!-- END .kampanjepin -->
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'Ingen kampanjer for øyeblikket!';
                    }
                ?>
            </div><!-- END #kampanjer-container -->
```

And my style:

```
#kampanjer-container {
    margin: 25px 0 0 -10px;
    width: 670px;
}

.kampanje-content {
    width: 182px;
}

.kampanjepin {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 182px;
}

.kampanjepin img {
    background-color: #ececec;
    max-width: 182px;
    max-height: 125px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.kampanjepin h3 {
    font-size: 0.850em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
    color: #000000;
}

.kampanjepin p {
    font-size: 0.750em;
}
```

If anyone can help me figure this out it would be great! :)

Michael

Comment: Do you have a live example of the issue instead of an image? In any case, it appears that you have forgotten to close the conditional statement and the post loop with <?php endif;?> and <?php endwhile;?> respectively. 

I can't be certain if that is causing the issue but I guess it's worth a short -- especially since the Masonry codes you declared seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

On hindsight, I'm quite certain that the layout issue is being caused by the open post loop -- especially since the Masonry declarations seem to be correct. Without closing the post loop, your codes when viewed in the browser under View Source would perhaps be something like this example with 2 posts:

```
<div id="kampanjer-container">

    <!--this is the first post-->
    <article class="kampanjepin">
        <img><!--this is the thumbnail-->
        <h3><!--this is the post title--></h3>
        <div class='kampanje-content'>
            <?php the_content() ?>
        </div>
    </article>
    <!--this is the first post-->

    </div><!--this is a stray closing tag from the parent container #kampanjer-container-->

    <!--this is the second post-->
    <article class="kampanjepin">
        <img><!--this is the thumbnail-->
        <h3><!--this is the post title--></h3>
        <div class='kampanje-content'>
            <?php the_content() ?>
        </div>
    </article>
    <!--this is the second post-->

    </div><!--this is a stray closing tag from the parent container #kampanjer-container-->

</div>
```

The reason for this occurrence is pretty simple: as long as the post loop is not closed with `<?php endwhile;?>`, the loop will continue to accept everything after `</article>` as being codes or content to be repeatedly used for each and every post pulled out to be displayed. The above example with the stray `</div>` might just be one of the many other things that is being included in the loop but it is more than enough to mess your layout up.

As such, you entire post loop should look something like this instead:

```
<div id="kampanjer-container"> <!--start of parent container-->

    <?php // define custom arguments
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'kampanje',
            'posts_per_page' => '15',
        );
        $kampanje = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php // start loop
        if($kampanje->have_posts() ) : while ( $kampanje->have_posts() ) : 
        $kampanje->the_post();
    ?>

        <!--post container-->
        <article class="kampanjepin">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
            <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
            <div class='kampanje-content'>
                <?php the_content() ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        <!--post container-->

    <?php // end loop
        endwhile;
    ?>

    <?php else:?> 

       <!--No post message-->
       <?php echo 'Ingen kampanjer for øyeblikket!'; ?>

    <?php // end conditional if statement
        endif;
    ?>

</div> <!--end of parent container-->
```

As you can see from the amended codes, `<?php endwhile; ?>` is placed directly after the closing `</article>` tag. This ensures that the post loop only uses the `<article>` tag and everything inside of it only. As such, the `<article>` tag will be applied consistently across every post.

Hope this helps to solve the issue!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out :) Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. What you says make sense so I'm quite surprised it didn't actually work out, though I do suspect the Masonry script isn't getting registered or at least it's not connecting to '.kampanjepin' yet. I still have to float the boxes to prevent it from just lining up vertically. Do you have any other suggestions that might clear it up? :)

Comment: no worries :) have you tried setting the position to relative for the .kampanjepin? also, do you have a live example of your site?

Comment: Yes, i tried that, but didn't work :/ I might have taken a cheap solution here, but I ended up using the columns solution, and add a script that let's older browsers use the new css tags. This works, but I still want to find out this problem though :) I got a tip saying that some of my other scripts (menu script, html5 script) might be interfering with the masonry script, maybe that's why?

Comment: yeah, it could be a JavaScript conflict but it's hard to diagnose anything without a live example with which we can apply the console to..